# creating file problem in sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am creating a music file as File file=new File("/sdcard//a.wav"),if(!file.exists())file.createNewFile();.But after creating this i am going to next screen and coming back to this screen.Now i m reading it using MediaPlayer as following

```
if(file.exists()){
    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(recordPath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();  }
```

But it is not playing that file.The control is not going inside at all.Someone has any idea?

Comment: That happens if the previous activity has been killed...

Comment: Thanks.I understand what you are trying to say.I just said this.But i m in one activity but i am flipping between two images with different sound.While i m coming back from one image to other it is not playing respective sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your manifest, be sure you have:

```
   <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

and also for getting the SDCard path you should use

```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Comment: I added the permission already.So no problem there.But i put Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in place of sdcard.It is showing same problem.